Toast Guardian Vs. Square KDS
I am working with a Toast branded device that I need to run Square KDS on. The device is an ELO 15in-I-series-4. I have successfully been able to install the the Square KDS apk through adb commands and the app will run. I have even gotten as far as inputting a device code to pair the KDS with my Square account. However, within seconds of the app and device being paired the Toast Guardian [app] will kill the app.
Any work around will do. I just need to be able to run Square KDS on several similar devices from Toast. Can I run an emulator? (None I have found will work.) Can I flash new firmware onto the device? Does anyone have a solution?
